# Delete text in switch

Tags: xaml, maui

I try to delete a text from a switch but i cant, the switch code is:

```
 <Switch x:Name="styleSwitch"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         Scale="1.3"/>
```

And the style is:

```
<Style TargetType="Switch">
        <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray400}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But appears a text right to the Switch and i don't know how to remove it:

[image: Desactivado]

[image: Activado]

It's a default project of Maui so i don't know where that text came from, i try to find it and remove but i can't.

I tried also adding a Label and binding to that switch like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/switch#data-bind-a-switch), but that doesn't work, just add a new label.

How can i do it?

**EDIT**
Just apear in Windows

**EDIT 2**

I put the steps to reproduce my problem:

Frist create a new Maui project:
[image: NewProject]

[image: NewProjectTwo]

[image: NewProjectThree]

Add in xaml MainPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SwitchWithText.MainPage">
             
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Spacing="25" 
            Padding="30,0" 
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Switch></Switch>

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                
            <Label 
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            
            <Label 
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button 
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 
</ContentPage>
```

And Just run on Windows Machine, the app show like this:

[image: SwitchWhithText]

[image: SwitchWhithTextTwo]

If you run it on Android, that text doesn't appears just appears in Windows desktop, i saw in Xamarin you can delete that with `ContentOff=""` or `ContentOn=""` but in MAUI you can't, i don't know if i need a library or what, i read all documentation about but i didn't saw nothing about.

Comment: Can you add more code so I can try and replicate this on my end

Comment: @FreakyAli its just a default proyect with out blazor, you just need a new project and add the switch element, by default the style is created

Comment: Cool let me quickly check it out

Comment: I did a test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem on my side on windows. Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Hello i edited to show how to reproduce, with a default project appears just on/off text, i changed some styles in my main project, the language to spanish and appears that long text who i want to destroy, but i dont find the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a known issue about swich in maui.

And you can follow up the issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6177 .

Thanks for your feedback about this problem.

Have a nice day.